# Tags and languages

Tags: discussion

I'm tracking the usage of languages over time. SO is great in this aspect because it allows me to access the data, but maybe you could help me narrow down which tags are programming languages. Maybe there's a way to derive this from the database?

I am currently using the tags for StackOverflow, and I have a good base, but there are many languages that I don't know, and I wanted some mechanism that was less labor intensive than looking in Wikipedia.

For example, HTML: not a language, rails: not a language, etc.

Comment: At a glance, their tag description seem to start all with "x is a programming language.." (with some variation though).

Comment: Did you check if the information you need is on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/163250)?

Comment: @Cupcake, yes. My SQL query gets the attributes for the tag, but I could not find a way to determine if the tag is for a language.

Comment: If anyone dared to actually categorise this it would result in a holy war...  you could automate your looking on Wikipedia?

Comment: As I commented [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262008/measure-popularity-of-programming-languages#comment50128_262008), SO questions are a bad metric of measuring programming language use. Your results would be rather biased towards entry level languages and technologies; a beginner or amateur using PHP or Java is simply more likely to ask a (often bad, duplicate) question than a professional working with prolog or fortran. Furthermore, the beginner questions are often tagged incorrectly and broader than neccessary. So take any results with a huge pinch of salt...